# Convert HTML to plain text using XSLT - apply-templates and order of content

Tags: xml, xslt, apply-templates

I am trying to convert HTML document into plain text document using XSLT. However, I am quite new to XSLT and I can't understand why ouput of my transformation is different from my desired output.

My input HTML document:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p class="first">First paragraph.</p>
  <p class="para">Regular paragraph 1.</p>
  <p class="para">Regular paragraph 2.</p>
  <p class="para">Regular paragraph 3.</p>
  <p class="last">Last paragraph.</p>
  <h2 class="someclass">Heading 2</h2>
  <p class="first">First paragraph 2.</p>
  <p class="para">Regular paragraph 4.</p>
  <p class="para">Regular paragraph 5.</p>
  <p class="para">Regular paragraph 6.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My desired output (plain text):

```
Heading (h1): Heading 1
Para (first): First paragraph.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 1.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 2.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 3.
Para (last): Last paragraph.
Heading (someclass): Heading 2
Para (first): First paragraph 2.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 4.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 5.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 6.
```

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:for-each select="//p[@class='first']">
            Para (first): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//p[@class='para']">
            Para (regular): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//p[@class='last']">
            Para (last): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//h1">
            Heading (h1): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="//h2[@class='someclass']">
            Heading (someclass): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result of applying above XSLT to input HTML document:

```
Para (first): First paragraph.
Para (first): First paragraph 2.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 1.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 2.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 3.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 4.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 5.
Para (regular): Regular paragraph 6.
Para (last): Last paragraph.
Heading (h1): Heading 1
Heading (someclass): Heading 2
```

What I want to do is to **put content of tags from HTML document into plain text in order content appears in HTML document**. What this tranformation does instead is to put all elements matching same XPATH after one another.

I suspect that solution is using [apply-templates](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_apply_templates.asp) element, however I do not understand how it works and hence have trouble using it for above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This transformation is doing exactly what you've told it to - first process all the `p[@class='first']` elements, then all the `p[@class='para']` etc.  Instead you are correct that you should define separate templates for each of the different cases and the use `apply-templates` to separate the issue of which elements to process from the issue of what to do with each one.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- process all the child elements of body in document order -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="html/body/*" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- if the element we're processing is a <p class="first"> ... -->
<xsl:template match="p[@class='first']">
    Para (first): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- etc. etc. -->
<xsl:template match="p[@class='para']">
    Para (regular): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[@class='last']">
    Para (last): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    Heading (h1): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h2[@class='someclass']">
    Heading (someclass): <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Not quite... to be totally general and handle any level of nesting, you need an apply-templates inside each template to continue the nested recursion.

Comment: @JimGarrison if there were any nesting in the input XML then yes, I was simply answering the question that was asked, namely how to do the same processing but get the results out in document order.

Comment: Thank you - seeing ``apply-templates`` used on that particular example made me understand how it works.